# Nginx & Chef: How do you create a scalable rule to listen on a specific interface?

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, recipe

In nginx, in order to listen on a specific interface (on a dual-homed server) you must declare the interface via IP address. Obviously this isn't scalable in a Chef recipe, as you can't have the IP be static but instead point to the server's interface. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chef uses Ohai to gather information about the system. The simple form is `node['ipaddress']` which is generally the IP corresponding to the interface with the default route. This might not always be what you want though, so we also have a hash of all interface under `node['network']['interfaces']` where you can iterate over them, find the interface you want, and grab its address. Run `ohai | less` from the command line to see all the data available to you.

Comment: Thank you for this response...I learned all of this shortly after posting, however it wasn't a solution for me. Since my server is dual-homed and Joyent manages NIC's through a different mechanism than the traditional /etc/network/interfaces file, I had to get creative. the node[ipaddress] attribute successfully got me eth1, but to get eth0 I had to create the file as a chef template, call out variables, and link them from the recipe file. The variable was created via a "shell_out" command with a creative ifconfig grep string. In case anyone else faces the same issue :)

Comment: `node['network']['interfaces']` gathers data directly from the kernel interface, nothing to do with `/etc/network/interfaces`. I would presume it works though Joyent might mean SmartOS and I have no idea if Ohai supports that userland.